# Using a form to insert an image using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using this javascript function to use a form to insert text into a set div.

I would like to be able to put an image url into a form and use this function to insert the url into an img tag instead of a div. What way could I achieve this?

Javascript:

```
function header01(){

    var head01v = document.getElementById('head01i').value;

    document.getElementById('head01c').innerHTML = head01v;
    document.getElementById('head01c').style.display = "block";

    return false;
}
```

I attempted to use the suggested solution, inputting the appropriate fields

```
 function image01(){

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = document.getElementById('imag01i').value;
        document.getElementById('imag01c').appendChild(img);

        return false;
    }
```

But to no avail, any additional help is greatly received.

Comment: `var img = document.createElement('img'); img.src = theValueOfTheForm;` Could that be of help?

Answer (score 1):

Extending my comment to an answer:

It isn't that hard. First, check if you have a valid URL (more info on that [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JavaScriptQuestions/25837-javascript-regex-validate-url.html) - first hit on [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=js+validate+url&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=nl&client=safari)), next, do this:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = [the validated URL you obtained from the form];
document.getElementById('theElementYouWantToInsertTheImgIn').appendChild(img);
```

Comment: thanks but attempted with no joy, have updated above question to what I tried.

Comment: What happens when you try my solution? @user1739696

Comment: Did the function actualiteit get called?

Comment: all is being used at http://barbsbristol.co.uk/, I have updated it with the your code suggestion, any ideas?